# Web API 2: Can a [FromBody] controller method parameter be optional if the controller method is overloaded with both [HttpPost] and [HttpGet]?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I sometimes want to Post a Query Object to Web Api 2, but most of the time I just want to use URI parameters to filter data returned by the controller method.  I tried this:

```
[HttpGet][HttpPost]
public ResultVM GetResult(
    [FromBody] QueryObjectVM query,
    ,[FromUri] int? custid = null,
    ,[FromUri] int? orderid = null
)
```

This works great as long as I Post with a Query Object in the body.  I can either include or not include the Uri parameters successfully too.  However, the Query Object fails the Data Binder on a Get because a HttpGet has no body.

I tried to make the query object optional, but this fails on both Get and Post.  Web API data binding does not like the optional null assignment:

```
[FromBody] QueryObjectVM query = null
```

If the answer is I must have a separate controller method for Post and Get, will Web API 2 handle a HttpGet calling a HttpPost and then return data successfully?  I cannot always call this method using Post calls.

Answer (score 0):

So far here's what I came up with, but I would rather figure out how to make the QueryObjectVM work as an optional parameter with HttpGet

```
[Route("GetResult")]
[HttpGet]
public ResultVM GetResult(
        [FromUri] int? custid = null
        , [FromUri] int? orderid = null
)
{   return this.GetResult(query: null, custid: custid, orderid: orderid);
}

[Route("GetResult")]
[HttpPost]
public ResultVM GetResult(
        [FromBody] QueryObjectVM query
        , [FromUri] int? custid = null
        , [FromUri] int? orderid = null
)
{  
    // Add optional Uri parameters to query object, query, and return the new result
}
```